# controller chaing in spring 3

Tags: spring-mvc

i have to call one controller on the basis of first controller i have to call another controller ......
but this is not working in spring 3 mvc........

```
@Controller
public class ajaxContoller {
      @RequestMapping(value="/mmiFacade",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public  @ResponseBody String mmiFacade(@RequestParam String sType){
                       String forwardName = "";          
        if (sType.equalsIgnoreCase("Pincode")) {

            forwardName = "forward:/pincodeAction";
        } else if (sType.equalsIgnoreCase("Locality")) {

            forwardName = "forward:/localityAction";
        } else if (sType.equalsIgnoreCase("Patient")) {

            forwardName = "forward:/patientAction";
        } else if (sType.equalsIgnoreCase("Dlhdata")) {

            forwardName = "forward:/Dlhdata";
        } 
           return forward;  

    }



    @RequestMapping(value="/pincodeAction",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String ajax(){
            return "hiii";

    }
 @RequestMapping(value="/localityAction",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String ajax1(){
            return "hiii1";

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return modelandview object. view name starting with "forward:/" will do the job, otherwise Spring does not even try to interpret the response.
Another option to implement a switch and to invoke other mapping as simple call to anther java function.

Comment: now the problem is that i got an error this.....org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'mmiController' bean method

Comment: I got an error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'mmiController' bean method

Comment: 'Ambiguous mapping found' means you mapping at least 2 methods to the same path. Check your @RequestMapping definitions

Answer (score 0):

Returning a String containing the view name does exactly the same thing as returning a ModelAndView object with the view name set to a String. If you just return a String, Spring internally creates a ModelAndView and set the view name to the value of the String.

In your example, you should not annotate the mmiFacade method with @ResponseBody. Using @ResponseBody bypasses the view resolution process, which is where the "forward:" and "redirect:" prefixes in view names are detected and processed.